# OrderBy in foreach loop does not work

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want the `foreach` statement to iterate through the list. What I want to achieve is to make sure that items with lowest rank is fetched first but the following code does not work. I know this might be because that `orderby` is not in-place sorting. what is the alternative way to make sure that small ranks are fetched first in foreach?

```
foreach(var item in Collection.Where(item => Valid(itemID)).OrderBy(item => item.Rank)))
{
    doWork(item);``
}
```

Update:
'Rank' is an `Enum`

```
public enum Rank
{
 A = 1,
 B = 2
}
```

Comment: How do you know it is not working? Provide your data and results. BTW you have an extra parenthesis at the end!

Comment: Don't know what the logic behind is, but maybe `OrderByDescending` ?

Comment: @Caramiriel `Rank` is an `enum`

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Does `doWork` employ threads?

Comment: @ChrisF Yes, but `Collection` is a thread-safe list implementing `iproducerconsumercollection`

Comment: If `Rank` is an enum, `OrderBy` will sort them by the numerical value of that enum. (The order in which you defined them)

Comment: @TimeMachine If your collection is `iproducerconsumercollection` then perhaps  the code probably just freezes on `OrderBy`? Am I right?

Comment: @TimeMachine - you might be kicking off each thread in the right sequence but there's no guarantee they'll process or complete in the same order.

Comment: @EugenePodskal Nope, nothing freezes, OrderBy does not order the list. However, one entry is allowed to the list at anytime.

Comment: @TimeMachine Please elaborate on what does "not work" exactly , or even better create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EugenePodskal Sorry, the very first statement that foreach fetches is an item with `rank` 2. However, the correct behavior is to fetch the item with `rank` 1 first.

Comment: @TimeMachine Are you sure that there are any items with rank 1 in the collection? If it is producer-consumer collection, then it is quite possible for it to have only some of the items you think it should contain. `ToArray` it, print it somewhere, and then OrderBy the `ToArray`ed array. If it will show items with `Rank` 1 before items with `Rank` 2, then I'd be surprised. I mean `Collection.ToArray().Where(item => Valid(itemID)).OrderBy(item => item.Rank)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach(var item in Collection.Where(item => Valid(itemID)).OrderBy(item => item.Rank.Value)))
{
    doWork(item);
}
```